# Moduli of smooth curves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, moduli-spaces

Why is the Moduli of smooth curves of a fixed genus not compact/proper?

I know that there is a compactification using stable curves. But is it easy to see that the Moduli of smooth curves is not compact?

Following Sam Need's comment, I should write that I am comfortable with the Moduli of smooth projective curves i.e., as an algebraic variety.

Comment: If one assumes the classical result that, for genus $g\geq2$, the moduli space of smooth curves is "the same" as the space of hyperbolic Riemann surfaces of genus $g$, then the noncompactness is easy to understand.  A classical paper by Milnor shows that when one tends to infinity in the moduli space, the [systole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systolic_geometry) of the surface tends to zero (and vice versa).  Of course this still leaves us with the task of actually constructing families of surfaces with systole tending to zero; this is a bit more complicated than the case of elliptic curves.

Comment: You need to improve the question by giving us a few hints about the background you want to assume. Which version of moduli space are you working with? What are its points, its topology? What background references are you comfortable with? And so on.

Comment: There are already plenty of answers/comments addressing your question. But for general *intuition*, if you have some moduli space which parameterizes objects which can degenerate to an object outside the class you're dealing with, then this indicates the   moduli space is not compact.

Comment: The easiest and most classical way to detect degeneration is by looking at a particular nonzero period and observe that it converges to zero as you move in a family of Riemann surfaces. Examples are easy to arrange by looking at hyperelliptic curves or at conformal connected sums of tori.

Comment: The closing votes on this question are unreasonable.  It is easy to say that the result is true because the bigshots proved it long ago, but it does appear to be a nontrivial task to give an accessible explanation of this.  Giving accessible explanations is of interest to research mathematicians and therefore legitimate on MO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is yet another approach. If $M_g$ were proper, its image in $A_g$ under the Torelli map would be closed. But products of lower dimensional Jacobians are in the closure. This last result is attributed to Matsusaka and Hoyt by Mumford in the article entitled "Further comments on boundary points" here: https://www.jmilne.org/math/Documents/woodshole.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Seeing that there are already two answers that are not entirely convincing, I decided to copy my *comment* to an *answer*.  If one assumes the classical result that, for genus g≥2, the moduli space of smooth curves is "the same" as the space of hyperbolic Riemann surfaces of genus g, then the noncompactness is easy to understand. A classical paper by Milnor shows that when one tends to infinity in the moduli space, the [systole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systolic_geometry) of the surface tends to zero (and vice versa).  Of course this still leaves us with the task of actually constructing families of surfaces with systole tending to zero; this is a bit more complicated than the case of an elliptic curve (i.e., a 2-torus).

Comment: The problem with this answer is that it requires two more pieces of work from the original asker: why is this "new" moduli space homeomorphic to the old one?  And (as you mention): why are there hyperbolic surfaces with systoles tending to zero?

Comment: One way of doing it is by looking at the particular case of the space of tori with one (geodesic) circle component, and showing that the boundary circle can be arbitarily short.  Then one can double this torus with boundary to get a genus 2 surface with small systole.  Any work with hyperbolic surfaces is going to involve more calculation than the case of elliptic curves, but it is easy enough to find papers dealing with the case of torus with boundary.  @SamNead

Comment: Yes, _I_ know that we can metrically pinch a curve, and _you_ know that too.... but it is not going to help the original poster.  (And, if we are going to pinch a curve then I prefer the family I gave in my answer. You can prove, using the euclidean metric, that there is a large modulus annulus about the points $z_{2g + 1}$ and $z_{2g + 2}$. Since moduli of annuli are conformal invariants, my family exits).

Comment: @SamNead, do you mean "exists"?

Comment: It exists _and_ it exits (moduli space).  The latter is the hard part.

Comment: So you are using "exits" in the sense of "tends to infinity in the moduli space", or "approaches the boundary at infinity".  Is this a standard term in algebraic geometry?  I am not sufficiently familiar with the field.  If not, the term is not immediately understood.

Comment: @SamNead, at any rate, I think the hyperbolic approach is more elementary.  You can construct hyperbolic surfaces by gluing together right-angled hyperbolic polygons.  So constructing surfaces with desired properties just boils down to the existence of certain rather simple polygons in the hyperbolic plane, with no fancy moduli space theory.  See e.g., Hyperbolic octagons and Teichmüller space in genus 2.  Aline Aigon-Dupuy; Peter Buser; Michel Cibils; Alfred F. Künzle; Frank Steiner. J. Math. Phys. 46, 033513 (2005)
https://doi.org/10.1063/1.1850177 based on earlier work by Buser and others.

Answer (score 2):

Is Arbarello's 74 paper (specifically, theorem 3.27 there) [Weierstrass points and moduli of curves](http://www.numdam.org/item/CM_1974__29_3_325_0.pdf) an easy enough argument ?

Answer (score -1):

Fix $g \geq 1$, a genus.  Fix $Z = (z_i)_{i = 1}^{2g + 2}$, a collection of distinct point in the plane. Define $C(Z)$ to be the curve in the complex projective plane obtained from the solutions of $y^2 = \prod (x - z_i)$. So $C(Z)$ is hyperelliptic.  Fixing the first $2g + 1$ points of $Z$, we move $z_{2g + 2}$ towards $z_{2g + 1}$.  This gives a non-constant family of curves.  The limiting curve is stable but not smooth, thus the moduli space is not compact.

Comment: "thus the moduli space is not compact": that's exactly the question — see @Will Sawin's comment.

Comment: @abx - I am giving a simple (well, simpler) example.  I assume that you agree that this family exits moduli space.  So, help me help the questioner.  How would you prove that the family exits?  (Without talking about metrics, or conformal invariants, which they presumably don't know about...)

Comment: I gave a simple construction in my comment. Anyway, I think the problem is not the construction of such a family, but the proof that its existence implies that the moduli space is not compact.

Comment: I wrote "exits" not "exists". The phrase "exits" is apparently not standard, but I meant it to mean "leaves every compact set" which in turn means "is not contained in any compact set".

Comment: Sorry, indeed I misread. I don't see an elementary way to prove that the family exits. As I wrote in a comment, I think one can give an argument based on the Picard-Lefschetz formula, but it requires some care, and is certainly not elementary.